# How to make component A display data at component B in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular-components

How do I go about writing logic in *component A* to accept input data from the user, and make those data display in a table found in *component B*?

Comment: depends how your project is organized. Is component A a subcomponent of component B ?

Comment: No! For instance, component A has a form where user can enters some set of data. And I want component B to render those inputted data from component A in a table form

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought but wanted to make sure. First of all, the best and recommend way of doing this is using a backend so each component can ask the server for the data it needs and submit whatever it has. If you only want Angular, you will need a shared service. Component A will save the data to a shared service and component B will pull it from there but obviously you would lose the data when the page refreshes or closes.

Comment: Losing the data when the page refreshes isn't a problem for now, all I want to know is how I can achieve it.. Beside, I can use LocalStorage API for that.